# How can liquibase banner be turned off in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase

I am setting up liquibase in a spring boot app. On app startup liquibase overrides default spring boot banner and shows a liquibase banner:

```
####################################################
##   _     _             _ _                      ##
##  | |   (_)           (_) |                     ##
##  | |    _  __ _ _   _ _| |__   __ _ ___  ___   ##
##  | |   | |/ _` | | | | | '_ \ / _` / __|/ _ \  ##
##  | |___| | (_| | |_| | | |_) | (_| \__ \  __/  ##
##  \_____/_|\__, |\__,_|_|_.__/ \__,_|___/\___|  ##
##              | |                               ##
##              |_|                               ##
##                                                ## 
##  Get documentation at docs.liquibase.com       ##
##  Get certified courses at learn.liquibase.com  ## 
##  Get advanced features and support at          ##
##      liquibase.com/support                     ##
##                                                ##
####################################################
```

How can I go back to default spring boot banner? I know that I can disable banners in spring boot, load a banner from a file, but I believe I should be able to explictly tell liquibase to stop showing it's banner.

Comment: The problem has been fixed in a new version of Liquibase, check my answer for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Liquibase 3.10.3/4.1.1 its banner [has been extracted](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/5e557a5c7999a3c91fc635a82712427421ad845a) to the separate file called `banner.txt`. So, starting from these versions, this file will be in the classpath if you have the `liquibase-core` dependency.

Surprisingly, Spring relies on a [file with the same name](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-banner) when it chooses the banner text. As a result, it takes Liquibase's banner accidentally and prints it. So, it's not really a fault of Liquibase.

Maybe we can raise an issue in Liquibase repo to ask them about renaming that file for the convenience of all Spring users. But for now, I see the only way to fix it - to use Spring's standard approaches of working with banners as you said (of course, it' always possible to downgrade Liquibase version too).

**EDIT:** Found that the issue about it has already been raised: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/1476

**EDIT 2:** The problem has been fixed in Liquibase 4.2.0 by moving the `banner.txt` to the different location. See [the release notes](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases/tag/v4.2.0).